# Php : Avoid database queries for each visitors

Tags: php, mysql, database, blogs, visitors

Today multiple questions came to me about how web servers work with a basic code of request in database and display to the front.

For the example of a blog where we want to display our posts
I don't know any other way than

- Query the database then stock the result in a php variable
- Foreach the variable in the front to display the different contents

as simple as that but the question is :

> Does the database query each time a visitor browse the web page supposed to display our posts ?

For me it has always worked as this. But now I'm asking myself why do we make requests on a table that we (the writers of the posts) update like one time each week everytime we visit the page ? In the case of a blog with thousands daily visitors while we update it every week, Do we query the database that much time ?

**The question is the same for the php process that "foreach" every posts** which require a little bit more process for the server before displaying the web page. Multiplied by the number of visitor.

> If it really works as I think, how do we avoid all of these ?

Comment: Why is it a concern? Depending on the load of webapp it may be using a great number of ways to optimize its response time: caches, DB replication, various in-memory storage engines. But there should be a solid reason to start optimization.

Comment: I actually never realized that optimization could go further that making better operations possible. And now I feel ashamed to been such an ignorant all that time ...

Answer (score 0):

Its sounds like you want to use Caching - there are simple ways to do this, and libraries/products that can help you see [this article](http://www.xeweb.net/2010/01/15/simple-php-caching/) and [this library](http://phpfastcache.com)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I spent too much time using things without even knowing what it is and how it works :(